# Any way to bypass force file download?

Tags: php, html, apache

Is there a way to avoid force-downloading a file?

Im uploading a file to a server, but i want that file to be executed when I access it, not downloaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Generally: no, not reliably. It would be a terrible security hole if you could. What kind of a file is it?

Comment: Of course there is, also there's a magical command that can let you access your teacher's email.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. It's a reasonable *question* even if it's a bad thing to want to do.

Comment: Close vote as not a real question, you don't supply operating system, PHP version, how did you installed PHP... If it's hosting company server, you should be asking support, not here.

Answer (score 4):

If the file is being download automatically which you expect to be executed, that means that you didn't add any rule for your file type, so Apache doesn't know if it should be executed.

Open your apache httpd.conf file, add

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>
```

Replace '.php' with any file extension/type. For example - .cgi file extension.

```
<FilesMatch \.cgi$>
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
 </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading a PHP file and expecting it to execute rather than download, it sounds as if your web server is not configured properly.  Make sure that you have PHP installed on your server and that Apache is configured to run scripts.  You will find loads of sets of instructions to do this depending on which platform you are on.

Comment: PHP is installed, but something in the server (its not my server) is forcing files to be downloaded instead of executed.